# matplotlib axis tick labels: getting mantissa and exponent

Tags: python, matplotlib, floating-point

Is there a way to separately get at the mantissa and exponent of axis tick labels so that I can manipulate how they are displayed? I need them to look like "5x10<sup>-9</sup>" instead of the usual scientific notation "5.0e-9".

If I was doing this in gnuplot I would do something like

```
set format y "%2.0t{/Symbol \327}10^{%L}"
```

The %2.0t gets me the mantissa and the %L gets me the exponent. How can I do the same thing in matplotlib?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib uses so-called Locators and Formatters which (independently) locate the ticks and label them ([Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html)). The standard `ScalarFormatter` takes an additional keyword argument (`useMathText`) which does exactly what you want.

To use it:

```
 # import the tickers
 import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

 # your plotting code 

 # create a new formatter and use it on the y-axis
 formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
 ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

I have answered a similar question in slightly more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917383/standard-form-matplotlib-change-e-to-times-10)

Comment: @TheBigH do you still need this? I guess its a bit an old question ;)

Comment: I don't really need it at the moment, but this will come in handy for next time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

what about using `str.split`:

```
In [242]: x
Out[242]: 5e-09

In [243]: '{}*10^{}'.format(*map(int, str(x).split('e')))
Out[243]: '5*10^-9'
```

Comment: I can't use string manipulations like that inside a formatter environments. I'm doing `majorFormatter = pylab.FormatStrFormatter( '%f' )`. Any string manipulations will of course be applied to the '%f' (or whatever), and not the 5.0e-9 that is later generated.

Comment: @TheBigH what do you have then?