# standard form matplotlib -- change e to \times 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, the axes are sometimes displayed in standard form. The numbers are shown by the ticks and something like '1e-7' appears by the axis. Is there a way to change that to a written out $\times 10^{-7}$?

I am not looking to change the labels on each individual tick. I am looking to change the text that appears once at the bottom of the axis saying '1e-7'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer: Use the latex mode:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

x = np.arange(10000, 10011)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Actually you don't need to use latex at all. The [`ScalarFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) which is used by default has an option to use scientific notation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

x = np.arange(10000, 10011)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x)
formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Daniel Marx does that solve the problem, or have I also misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yes, it works thanks! For some reason though it returns an error even though the plot is produced: RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:

Comment: @DanielMarx Where? 
See my update, you don't need latex at all

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [matplotlib.ticker](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html). It allows you control of the formatting of ticks including the labels.

Comment: Thanks but I can't see how to produce what I'm looking for.

Comment: From the documentation "You can derive your own formatter from the Formatter base class by simply overriding the _ _call_ _ method. The formatter class has access to the axis view and data limits."

Comment: It's not the tick formatting I'm looking to change. As tom said above, it's the offset text.